# Missing Parameter request from middleware in Request Form in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

As mention in https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/10791

If we want to get the `Merge request` from middleware in the `Form request`

We could add the below function in our `Form request`

```
public function all()
{
    $this->merge( $this->request->all() );
    return parent::all();
}
```

But when i tried to use that function in my `CartRequest` i get an error

> (2/2) **ReflectionException**
>
> Class App\Http\Requests\Product\CartRequest does not exist
>
> in **RouteSignatureParameters.php** (line 25)

I dont know why i could not use that method

**NB** : im using **laravel 5.5**

Rigth now, i call 2 request in my controller to get my custom request

```
function addCart(Request $request,CartRequest $cartRequest,$item_id){
    $global_id = $request->globalId //this id is coming from middleware
}
```

But i think that is the bad method.

Is there any other method to get our custom request in middleware?

Comment: why do you need 2 request objects?

Comment: because i could not get my request from middleware. and i have said it that is the bad method @madalinivascu

Comment: why do you have a request in the middleware?

Comment: because i want to return a global variable id to all my controller.

Comment: where does that global variable come from? a  form filed? a php variable ? by all my controller you mean to all routes get/post/put/delete?

Comment: from database, yes is for post get put delete @madalinivascu, any problem for it ?

Comment: why not use a session variable?

Comment: if i cold i would. If u are know right about the middleware u will understand about what i mean @madalinivascu

Comment: why not use the id as a param for your routes?

Comment: the request object deals with input from forms, your id is from the database

Comment: so you don't need 2 request objects

Comment: I think you might be better off explaining the original problem you're trying to solve, whilst also posting all relevant code. There's nothing in the code you've posted called `AddCartRequest`, which presently is the source of your error.

Comment: @fubar ignore the AddCartRequest, in stack i just forget rename it

Comment: @fubar and i think i dont need to extend my CartRequest code there should be not a problem on my request before i am adding the function all(). I am using artisan to create my request.

if you are asking where i put my public function all, i am putting the function right below the class name